# Why is my functioning giving me a "expected primary-expression before '}' token" while using a goto?

Tags: c++, debugging, goto

My function is giving me  "expected primary-expression before '}' token" while using a goto and I don't know why.

This code worked as-is in main before I put it into a function.

It works when I replace the 'goto' with 'break', but I need to know why this is.

```
void fileInputLoop(ifstream& inputFile){
    do{

        cout << "Enter data file name: ";
        getline(cin, fileName);
        previousFileName = fileName;
        // The user will press enter to exit data input 
        if(fileName == ""){
            // If no file name is entered, exit this input loop
            goto skip_data_input_loop;

        }else{
            // Check to see if input is an existing file
            inputFile.open(fileName);
            if(!inputFile.is_open()){
                cout << "File is not available." << endl;
            }else{
                // FILE IS OPEN, DO SOMETHING WITH IT
                ReadData(inputFile);
                inputFile.close();
            }
        }
        // If a second++ file is read in, the previous file will be set accordingly
        // This is to track if a duplicate is from the same file or a new file
        previousFileName = fileName;

    }while(true);
    skip_data_input_loop:
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `goto` and labels to [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) out of loops.

Comment: Feel free to justify your demand.

Comment: Goto is generally considered harmful, and tend to promote spaghetti code that is hard to read, understand, follow and maintain. For such simple code as in the example there's not much difference between your `goto` and `break`, but work with it a couple of years and the labels might no longer be where you once put them, making the name misleading and the `goto` jump over more than `break`. The `break` statement is known when you see it, you know that it will end the current loop, a `goto` is unknown, you don't really know where it will jump.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude without wishing to start a holy war, it's also true the `break` can change meaning with edits. If another inner loop is added, for example, `break` would behave as if the label had been moved to just outside the inner loop. In that case, `goto` would not suffer in the same way.
Admittedly, in this case, break would seem to be the cleaner way.

Comment: @RichardHodges - No going for an holy-war, just want to say that the lesson to take from this is the one uncle Bob has been teaching for years. Better to write small self-contained functions that can simply return early.

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree with that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that labels are to label a statement. In other words, you can't have a label without a statement following.

With the caveat of my comment, you could solve it by having an empty "null" statement after the label:

```
skip_data_input_loop: /* Empty statement using the semicolon */ ;
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `break` is the recommended keyword to be used.

Comment: So, it worked when it was in main because there was code that followed it?

Answer (score 1):

The Format of goto statement is below syntax

```
goto label;
... .. ...
... .. ...
... .. ...
label: 
statement;
... .. ...
```

As in case of main you would have had a return statement below the label and for this function the label at the end of function is immediately followed by the end } of the function they as per syntax a statement or expression is expected after the label.

you can use a print statement or an Empty return

Example:

```
    }while(true);
    skip_data_input_loop:
    return;
}
```